# Using setTimeout in setState callbacks

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in a react component:

```
  calcTime: function() {
    time = <some time dependant value>
    this.setState({
      total_time: time
    }, window.setTimeout(this.calcTime, 1000));
  }
```

This works fine, except that while it's running I see the following exception in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant
>   Violation: enqueueCallback(...): You called `setProps`,
>   `replaceProps`, `setState`, `replaceState`, or `forceUpdate` with a
>   callback that isn't callable.

I did think initially that this was down to having the setTimeout function there, so I extracted that out to another function and just added that as the callback method.  However, when doing this, `render` stopped showing the updates to the DOM.

How should I do this correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second argument in [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) should be `function`., [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) returns `number` but not reference to `function`

```js
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      total_time: 0
    }
  },
  
  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.calcTime();
  },
  
  calcTime: function() {
    var time = this.state.total_time + 10;
    
    this.setState({
      total_time: time
    }, () => { 
      window.setTimeout(this.calcTime, 1000)
    });
  },
  
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.state.total_time}</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```